# string to type function, template specialization to make call uniform

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

Is there a unique way to achieve a uniform call syntax for a convert function like the following for any kind of type? The function takes a string and converts it into the given TYPE (here `int` and `MyMatrix<double>::Vector3` , call by reference of course!!)

```
int a;
std::string b = "asd";

stringToType::call(a,b);

MyMatrix<double>::Vector3 g; // Vector3 might be any type e.g  Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1>
stringToType::call(g,b);
```

e.g:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyMatrix{
    typedef Eigen::Matrix<T,3,1> Vector3;
};
```

I would like that the convert function converts types in the form of `Eigen::Matrix<T,3,1>` with `T` arbitary with the same function,

It should also support the basic types which have no template parameters (like the `int`)

Comment: the ``call`` function should do some convertion (not important) from the given string into the type given

Comment: Pretend for a moment you're someone that *doesn't* know what *you* are thinking when reading what you *wrote* here. The state your *problem* in a way that is understandable. (And no partial specialization doesn't mean you can't *overload*, which is what you should be doing).

Comment: thanks for the fast help but please reread it should be clearer now

Comment: It is much better to use C++11 style using declaration, as `template<typename T> using Vector3 = Eigen::Matrix<T,3,1>;` so you can use `Vector3<double> g;` Looks much clean!

Comment: Yes of course thanks!, right now I am not yet using these c+11 features...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

namespace details
{
    template <typename T>
    struct stringToTypeImpl
    {
        void operator () (std::stringstream& ss, T& t) const
        {
            ss >> t;
        }
    };

    // And some specializations
    template <typename T, int W, int H>
    struct stringToTypeImpl<Eigen::Matrix<T, W, H> >
    {
        void operator () (std::stringstream& ss, Eigen::Matrix<T, W, H>& t) const
        {
            for (int j = 0; j != H; ++j) {
                for (int i = 0; i != W; ++i) {
                    stringToTypeImpl<T>()(ss, t(i, j)); //ss >> t(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}

template <typename T>
void stringToType(const std::string& s, T& t)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    details::stringToTypeImpl<T>()(ss, t);
}


int main() {
    std::string s = "42";
    int i;

    stringToType(s, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: jeah, thats it , the important part i was missing was the redirection to details::stringToTypeImpl<T> and the fact that i can add template parameters while i specialize it, i wasnt aware of this ! thanks a lot

Comment: the follow up question is the following:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823564/partial-specialzation-with-dependent-name-typename